# Dynamic From URI Camel

Tags: apache-camel

So, I have been use Camel with Jboss fuse for a few days, and am stuck on designing a camel route.  What I have is an api that returns JSON objects and that can be accessed from a url and which requires a start and end time in UTC milliseconds such as `http://somelog.com?start=1465325280000&end=1465325281000`

What I would like to do is have camel fetch the JSON objects from the api every `dx` milliseconds and begin at time `x_i`

I thought about used a timer with the date function, but the date command does not provide UTC milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a camel:timer to trigger a Processor that builds the URL you need to invoke, then set it as header 'Foo'. You should be able to then reference in route using RecipientList EIP, like so:

```
  from("timer:tmr...")
      .to("bean:uriBuilder")
      .recipientList("${Foo}")
      .to("bean:resultsHandler");
```

Comment: I believe your answer would work, but I ended up finding a non camel based solution which was hiding in the rest api that I'm calling. Thanks!